# Is there a limit on the size of data I can fit in EventEmitter?

Tags: angular6

I have a component `A` which on start up receives few images from the server. On clicking a button, `A` should show component `B` which also needs the images. Could I just emit the image data from `A` to `B` or is it better that I resend the images' data to `B` from the server?